# Behaviour of comparison between int and tuple

Tags: python, python-2.x

For some reason

```
999 < (0, 6, 7, 8)
```

Evaluates to `True`

In fact, all tuples appear to be greater than all ints.

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons),

> Instances of `tuple` or `list` can be compared only within each of their types.

Is there documentation for this behaviour? Is there some implicit casting happening?

Comment: not sure how you are running this because this gives a `TypeError`

Comment: please upgrade from python 2 to python 3

Comment: No casting, it goes (illogically) off lexigraphical ordering of the type name in 2.7. We did away with this in Python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation you linked, when it discusses comparing tuples to other types:

> ordering comparison across these types gives an arbitrary order.

So, it sounds like this behavior is undefined in Python 2 (correct me if I'm wrong). Doing this same comparison in Python 3 gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    print(999 < (0, 6, 7, 8))
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'tuple'
```